# Equivalent of Goroutines in Clojure / Java

Tags: java, concurrency, clojure, go, goroutine

I recently enjoyed watching the [Google IO talk on Go Concurrency patterns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=f6kdp27TYZs)

Although the Go approach to concurrency (groutines, communication over channels) is clearly different to Clojure (immutability, manged references, STM), it seemed like the Go approach could still be useful in some circumstances in a Clojure context.

So is there a direct equivalent in Clojure or Java for Go's concurrency primitives (perhaps a library), in particular:

- `channel`-like objects that block until a reader and writer are available at both ends
- A `select`-like construct that can wait for results on multiple channels

**P.S.** Perfectly happy with a Java solution since it would be easy to use from Clojure

**UPDATE** Since the question was originally asked, Clojure now has [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) which provides all this functionality and more.

Comment: As of now, the answer is obvious: core.async. This question should probably be update to reflect this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async). It is a library written by Rich Hickey that implements go style channels.

Answer (score 3):

> channel-like objects that block until a reader and writer are
>   available at both ends

This is a bit confusing.  Do you mean "blocks until, if writing, a reader is available or, if reading, a writer is available"? I am speaking on behalf of the threads and not the construct, a construct cannot block only threads can. (To avoid confusion a construct would instruct threads to block).

If my assumption is true there are two options you can have (in standard Java).

1. [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)
2. [TransferQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TransferQueue.html) (though this can be used as a buffer channel also)

> A select-like construct that can wait for results on multiple channels

As far as I know there arent any true `select` like constructs.  The closest you can have is a [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) that will return when the next available task submitted is completed.

Comment: thanks and I think your interpretation is correct: SynchronousQueues do seem to be equivalent to Go channels.

Comment: Don't know much about go channels - but j.u.c.Exchanger is sometimes useful for pipelines. It's kindof a bi-directional SynchronousQueue, where an object is swapped in *both* directions.

Comment: @sw1nn I did initially have Exchanger in but the underlying difference betweeen an Exchanger and a go channel is that an Exchanger requires each Thread be a reader and a writer where as the channel requires one thread be a reader and one thread be a writer.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently written [go-lightly](https://github.com/midpeter444/go-lightly), a Clojure library to support programming with Go concurrency constructs, putting some Clojure idioms on that concurrent programming style.

The core constructs of Go concurrency programming are:

1. Go routines
2. Synchronous (blocking) channels
3. Bounded, mostly asynchronous (non-blocking) channels
4. A `select` operator that reads the next available message from multiple channels
5. Timeout operations on channel read/writes/selects

The go-lightly library has all of these features, building on top of features available in Java and Clojure.  True Go routines are multiplexed onto threads, rather than fully using a thread for its full lifetime.  In go-lightly, I build go routines on top of the Clojure future macro, so this is the weakest part of the Go model on the JVM.

I tried using lamina, but it lacks bounded channels (which you might want in some scenarios and is a part of the Go buffered channel model) and as far as I can tell lacks a way to have a producer block when putting a message onto a channel.  That is a crucial feature of the Go concurrency model.

I've included a number of examples using the go-lightly library in the git repo.  Most are based on examples that Rob Pike has given in talks over the past two years.

It would be interesting to build a Clojure library on top of JCSP, but I haven't researched that yet.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything about Go, have a look at Lamina to see if it fits what you are looking for https://github.com/ztellman/lamina

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Quasar/Pulsar](http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/post/49445260575/quasar-pulsar). It's very new, but it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Is Quasar usable as a Java library? I can't seem to find any clear instructions on how to use Quasar with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Joxa](http://joxa.org). It is a Clojure-like dialect of Lisp targeting Erlang Virtual Machine.

And [Erlang](http://Erlang.org) is known for light-weight sub-1000-bytes processes.

Also [Erjang](http://Erjang.org) is somewhat related and could be of interest to you. It's an implementation of Erlang Virtual Machine on top of JVM.

So *theoretically* you can compile Joxa to BEAM and then still run it on JVM. Not that I would recommend it :-).

Answer (score 0):

the [akka actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/java/untyped-actors.html) ~= goroutine+channel

Comment: But actors should not do any blocking work like db calls as the thread would block for that time, but blocking goroutines can be multiplexed(context-switched) on the threads. So, it's apple and oranges

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [**JCSP**](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/), based on the Occam/transputer algorithms. Key parts of this API implementation have been checked for correctness using formal methods and formal prover algorithms, so are about as reliable as is possible (the Alternative class is the prime achievement in this regard).

JCSP is very good ... however the downside remains the limitations imposed by the JVM, especially the high cost of threads. In Go or Occam, threads can number in millions, but not so on the JVM.